# Can this wave function be normalized?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction, normalization

This question I am stuck on goes like this:

> The ground state wave function for the electron in a hydrogen atom is $c\ e^{-r/a}$ where $r$ is the radial coordinate of the electron, $c$ is a constant and $a$ is Bohr's radius. Show that the wave function as given is normalized.

I tried doing the integration and don't get a finite result as is obvious by the graph of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you're dealing with a radial wavefunction, $r$ is only defined for $r>0$ usually (*negative* radii, if you want to consider them as "behind" the origin on the *negative* part of an axis through the origin, are already accounted for by integrating over the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ to get the factor of $4\pi$ that appears in the integrals below).

I assume you attempted to evaluate the following integral:

$$4\pi\int^\infty_{-\infty}r^2\psi^*\psi\text{ d} r$$

which indeed will diverge.

The integral you're looking to perform is

$$4\pi\int^\infty_{0}r^2\psi^*\psi\text{ d} r$$

which *is* finite.

Hope that helps?